# Is it a correct / not dangerous / common approach to pass an 'ActiveRecord::Relation' object as a method parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know if it is a correct / not dangerous / common approach to pass an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object as a method parameter.

At this time I am planning to use this approach in a scope method of a my model this way:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_active_associations(associations, active = nil)
    # associations.class
    # => ActiveRecord::Relation

    case active
    when nil
      scoped
    when 'active'
      with_ids(associations.pluck(:associated_id))
    when 'not_active'
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

*Note I*: I would like to use this approach for performance reasons since the `ActiveRecord::Relation` is lazy loaded (in my case, if the `active` parameter value is not `active` the database is not hit at all).

*Note II*: the usage of the `pluck` method may generate an error if I pass as `association` parameter value an `Array` instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In my opinion it's a sound tradeoff, you lose the ability to send an array as argument but you gain some perfomance. It's not that strange; for example, every time you define a scope you are doing exactly that, a filter than works only on relations and not on arrays.

2) You can always add `Enumerable#pluck` so the method works transparently with arrays. Of course it won't work if you use more features of relations.

```
module Enumerable 
  def pluck(method, *args) 
    map { |x| x.send(method, *args) } 
  end 
end
```

Comment: I cannot find out examples or blog posts where this approach of passing `ActiveRecord::Relation` as method parameter is used and/or explained. Can you link someone of those (if you know and/or can find one)?

Comment: i don't know of blogs commenting on this, but it doesn't seem like a big deal to me...